Can you use a fingerprint scanner over ssh on the remote?
When connected to a remote Linux computer over ssh, I'd like to use my fingerprint scanner to authenticate for sudo commands - much like you can when a using a fingerprint scanner on desktop Linux.
I am using various client operating systems - Windows, Linux and MacOS.
Is this possible?

no, it is hardware. the only way would be, that you use a network based USB emulator, but product suggestions are off topic on serverfault.com
